# Context API with agGrid cell renderers

Tags: ag-grid

When I use custom renderers, they are rendered outside of root application component and outside contexts.

As a result, when `Context.Consumer` is used inside cell renderer then `Context.Provider` is not found.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

first: you can bind your component for re-using like :

```
this.gridOptions = {
    context:{
        mainGrid: this -- wouldn't be accessible via cellRenderer params but on some methods will work
    },
}
```

second: on any `event` of `ag-grid` `params` are passed, and `params` property contains `api` property which represents a `GridApi`- seems exactly what you need.

Comment: cant find in documentation but you are totally right. the context is not available on all methods trough its params which is really bad. i need this on onGridReady and its not accessible there so had to move this method outside the gridoptions.

Comment: @pinarella it's isn't bad, it's just a proper isolation level, glad that my post helped you,
Btw - even so - this is a hack - and I'm recommending to think about better and proper design to avoid such tricks